# find the average of pairs with the same first element. kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of pairs in  `myPairs: List<Pair<String, Double>>` and need to calculate the average of each set of pairs with the same first element.

I came up with this code. It finds separately the sum and the count for each group, then divides in  by the count in a loop to find the average.

```
val myAverages = myPairs.groupingBy { it.first }.fold(0.0) { sum, element -> sum + element.second }.toMutableMap()
val myCounts = myPairs.groupingBy { it.first }.eachCount()

for ((myStr, count) in myCounts) {
        myAverages[myStr] = myAverages[myStr]!!.div(count)
    }

return myAverages
```

I wonder if there a more elegant/Kotlin-esque  way to solve this by using aggregate or fold functions?   My solution works but looks really ugly to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group your data set using `groupBy` `function`. Once you have the grouped `map` then you can `map` its values (`List<Pair<String,Double>>`) to the required average using the `average` `function`.

```
var mapOfAverages = myPairs.groupBy   { it.first }
                           .mapValues { it.value.map { pair -> pair.second }.average() }
```

This will give you a `map`, where `key` is first element of your `Pairs` and value is the average of all the second elements for this particular key.

Comment: your line looks very nice and it works. feels a bit un-intuitive to come up with this, but then again i'm only working with kotlin for about a week :)